# Как в Python тестировать асинхронный HTTP-stream?

Tags: python, python-3.x, юнит-тесты, потоки-данных, pytest

Имеем сервер, который через HTTP-поток отдаёт события в виде машиночитаемых текстовых сообщений. Одна строка — одно событие. Сообщения добавляются в поток асинхронно с относительно большими временными интервалами. Всё это время поток висит открытым на чтение по «Connection: keep-alive».

Есть метод класса, который должен слушать этот поток и вызывать обработчики событий внутри класса.

Необходимо протестировать работу этого метода средствами unittest.

Для других методов, работающих с HTTP-запросами использую возможности пакета requests_mock. Но в данном случае не получается придумать конструкцию, имитирующую этот поток и в процессе проверяющую состояния класса.

Был ли у кого подобный успешный опыт?

UPD. Конкретный код, что нужно оттестировать (этот код полностью рабочий, просто не покрыт тестами, что и пытаюсь исправить):

```
def listen_alarms(self, channel=0, alarms=None):
    """Listen for alarms from device."""

    def listener():
        resp = requests.get(url, params=urlencode(params), auth=auth,
                            timeout=TIMEOUT, stream=True)
        if self.debug:
            _LOG.debug("_query ret %s", resp.status_code)

        if resp.status_code == 200:
            for line in resp.iter_lines(chunk_size=1, decode_unicode=True):
                if line:
                    if self.debug:
                        _LOG.debug("Alarm: %s", line)

                    date, time, alert, state, _ = str(line).split(';', 5)
                    timestamp = datetime.strptime(date + ' ' + time,
                                                  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                    state = int(state)

                    self._handle_alarm(timestamp, alert, state)

    if alarms is None:
        alarms = {}

    url = self.get_url('alarmchangestate')

    if self.debug:
        _LOG.debug("Querying %s", url)

    params = self.params
    params.update({
        'channel': channel,
        'parameter': ';'.join(alarms),
    })

    # Add authentication data
    params.update({
        'user': self.username,
        'pwd': self.password,
    })
    auth = HTTPBasicAuth(self.username, self.password)

    import threading
    thread = threading.Thread(target=listener)
    thread.start()

    if self.debug:
        _LOG.debug("Return from listen_alarms()")
```

Comment: А конкретный пример кода можно? Так только либы `pytest-asyncio` да `pytest-aiohttp` посоветовать можно, без конкретики. Есть еще `aioresponses`, функционал `requests-mock` для `aiohttp`.

Comment: Добавил код в основной текст — сюда не пролазит…

Comment: Ну так а где тут асинхронность? Просто код в потоке, ну так и патчи как обычно, `with requests_mock.mock() as m: m.get('http://fizz', status_code=999); listen_alarms()` и т.д. Моки хотя и не thread safe, но если мок-объекты не меняются после создания, проблем не будет.

Comment: Другой вариант - замокать сервер, который будет выдавать нужные ответы на нужные запросы и вообще не заморачиваться моканьем `requests`.

Comment: Вообще, в таком запутанном коде (уж извини за критику), тут если писать юнит-тесты, то сначала надо делать рефакторинг капитально. Я бы начал с замоканного сервера и моканья только ссылок в коде и написал несколько интеграционных тестов, чтобы знать, что рефакторинг ничего не ломает. Потом разбил код в кучу простых функций, накидал для них юнит-тестов, завершающий этап - обновить или дополнить интеграционные тесты. Как-то так.

Comment: Да, это просто код в потоке. Но сообщения от реального сервера приходят асинхронно с основным потоком.
То, что код запутанный — возможно. Не пытался написать его лаконично. Прошу извинить…
Хотя для меня он простой и понятный :)